# Combine NaN value in rows - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, join

I would like to know if it's possible to combine some rows if we have in specific columns NaN value ? But the order can be change. I thought combine the rows if Name is duplicated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'Name': ['Jacque','Paul', 'Jacque'], 'City': [np.nan, '4', '10'], 'Birthday' : ['1','2',np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

[image]

And I would like to have this output :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check with `sorted`

```
out = df.apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key=pd.isnull)).dropna()
     Name  City  Birthday
0  Jacque   4.0       1.0
1    Paul  10.0       2.0
```

Comment: Hello, thank you but in fact the order can be change and the format is string not numerical